# window.opener.location.href not working in IE 6

Tags: javascript

window.opener.location.href = newUrl not working in IE 6

I want to refresh my parent window from popup window to some different URL, But above javascript code is not working.

Please let me know any solution or work around.

Thanks.

Comment: Not working means what? Browser catches fire? An Error?

Answer (score 1):

As I recall you can simply use `window.opener.location = newUrl` in IE6

Answer (score 0):

Did you load another page into the popup before you executed the script, if so, you need to name the parent window and do window.open(url,"parentWindowName")